# Chart is Not Defined' Issue in Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, chart.js

I am having an issue with my Laravel application where the chart is not defined. I have included the necessary code in my app.js file, as shown here:

[image]

[image]

I have also made sure to include the code where the chart should be displayed:

[image]

I have installed the needed package via npm and have placed the imports in the app.js file. After running dev, I tried using a CDN which solved the issue for me. However, the chart from npm is still not working.

Can anyone help me figure out why?

Images of the code and error can be found here: